# Efficient way of rereading file contents in c++

Tags: c++

I have basic code that looks like this:

```
while(inputfileStream.good())
{
    for(int i = 0;i<levels;i++)
    {
        inputfileStream.open(_file,ios::in | ios::out | ios::binary);
        for(int i = 0,kPOS=0;i<=fsize;i++,kPOS++)
        {
            if(kPOS > Ksize)
                kPOS=0;
            char tempchar = 0;
            inputfileStream.seekg(i,ios::beg);
            inputfileStream.get(tempchar);
            tempchar+=(int)_encription_key[kPOS];
            inputfileStream.seekg(i,ios::beg);
            inputfileStream.put(tempchar);
        }
        inputfileStream.close();
    }
}
```

It's a basic encrypter. I just have one problem: For each level of encryption I have to reopen the file to get its contents. Otherwise if I do not do this I have the same old text when I decrypt the file from each level.

Could you help me out and give a more efficent way of rereading the files contents besides calling `open()` and `close()`?

Comment: Perhaps you're still editing at this point, but please fix your indentation, as well as the capitalization and punctuation in your question.

Comment: Not to mention spelling; it's "encrypt" not "encript". Also note that most names beginning with underscores are reserved for the implementation...

Comment: Seems like corectness of indentation is pretty subjective thing :)

Comment: This post is terrible. Please fix it.

Comment: I tried to fix your question as well as I could. Have a look at the differences. If you make your question well formatted and readable, you'll be more likely to get an answer. If it's difficult to read, people might not bother.

Comment: And don't do this if(kPOS > Ksize) kPOS=0; There's not some limit on teh amount {}s you can put in your code.

Comment: @TonyHopkinson: Actually that is completely proper and appropriate.

Comment: But harder to read, harder to see and leaves next coder wondering whether you nissed the opening brace out, especially when the rest of them are all over the place. Terseness is for people who don't like lengthy explanations of where they went wrong.

Comment: Meh - if you want significant whitespace and indentation, use python, although, admittedly, if I was posting a question on SO I'd make it neat and tidy

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of closing and opening the file, you can

1. flush() the written content
2. sync() the content to the read buffer
3. seekp() the put pointer to the start of the file on each iteration

This may be clearer to you if you set exceptions() on your fstream.  You are most likely not seeing your encryption working at some points due to the fstream not being in the good() state.